# Why people donate hair on funeral of relatives?

Tags: belief, customs

In some Hindu communities, on death of father, son removes his own hair and keep a choti (a small bundle of hair on head at tail part.). What is the reason for  shaving the hair?

Comment: Since the part of the question that was duplicative has been removed, I'm reopening the question.

Comment: @sv. Since the question you are referring to has an answer, can this question marked as duplicate even though this is an old one?

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes, that's why I VTC'ed this one. I think it doesn't matter whether a question is old or new to mark as dup.