# Why shave hair after parents die?

Tags: belief, rituals, dharma, death, parents

Recently, a cousin of mine lost his father. Before conducting a ritual for the well being of his father's soul, he had to shave all his hair except for a bit at the back (*choti*). Why did he have to do this?

Comment: See [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16133/2995) answer.

Comment: They have to do that primarily because the Shastras instruct them do so..But apart from that what kind of "reasons" do u want?

Comment: BTw,[here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8190/why-people-donate-hair-on-funeral-of-relatives) is a similar question..

Comment: As per the Hindu religion to shave hair after the death of the parents is for to show the sadness. And it means you are in sad and if you shave then you are leaving all the old things. And when new hair grows you will opt for the new and positive energy for the happy life.

Comment: @Rickross I just wanna know through the shastras the reason for shaving the hair. There must be a reason why men must shave hair after the death of his parents.

Comment: @Utsav In my limited study of shastras i have found that shastras just tell us what is to be done and what is not to be done..Mostly they won't  elaborate on the "why" part..Sometimes they do but mostly they don't bother giving reasons..

Comment: Anyways ,sv's answer is indicative as to why..In general shaving off one's hair is a part of prayaschitta(atonement) I have always seen that..So it  surely has something to do with removal of sins...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why people donate hair on funeral of relatives?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8190/3500)

Comment: @Rickross ok it doesn't say why but can you tell me whose instructions these were? A rishi muni, A god e.t.c

Comment: @Utsav Those who are eligible for performing Shraddha of deceased parents should shave their heads..This is mentioned in some Scriptures..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the funeral rites mentioned in Garuda Purāṇa say so.

From [Chapter 4](https://archive.org/stream/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201#page/n751/mode/1up), Preta Kāṇḍa (Dharma Kāṇḍa) of Garuda Purāṇa:

> Śrī Kṛṣṇa said:
>
> कि दानमिति प्रश्नस्योत्तरमीरितम्॥ दाहमृत्योरन्तरे किमिप्रश्नोत्तरं शृणु ॥४०॥
>
> 40. I have given the answer to your queries about
>   gifts. **Now, I shall tell you about the obsequies and the funeral
>   rites of the deceased**.
>
> **...**
>
> प्रेतपिण्ड प्रदद्याच्च दाहातिशमनं खग॥ ततः प्रदक्षिणां कृक्त्वा चिताप्रस्थानवीक्षकाः॥ ६९॥ 
>   कनिष्ठपूर्व्वाः स्नानार्थं गच्छेयुः सूक्तजापकाः॥ ततो जलसमीपे तु गत्वा प्रक्षाल्य चांशुकम्॥७०॥
>
> 69-70. O bird, Preta-pinda is given in order to comfort
>   the deceased. Then having circumambulated the pyre and
>   casting a mournful look at it, **the mourners** should go for bath
>   muttering the hymn, with the youth marching ahead.
>
> 71.
>   Then having reached water and washed cloth, they
>   should wear the same saying for the deceased — we are taking bath.
>
> कुरुध्वमित्येव विदेच्छतवर्षावरे पुत्राद्या वृद्धपूर्वास्ते एकवस्त्राः **शिखांविना**॥७२॥ 
>   प्राचीनावीतिनः सव्र्वे विशेयुर्मौनिनो जलम्॥ अपनःशोशुचदघमनेन पितृदिङमुखाः॥७३॥
>
> 72-73. Then they all, each wearing one cloth only, **with
>   shaven heads**, wearing the sacred thread over the right shoulder
>   should enter water silently.
>
> जलावघट्टनं चैव न कुय्र्युः स्नानकारकाः॥ ततस्तटे समागत्या शिखां बद्धा ऋजून् कुशान्॥७४॥ 
>   दक्षिणाग्रहस्तयोस्तु कृत्वाथ सतिलं जलम्॥ आदायाद्भलिना याम्यां दुःखी पैतृकतीर्थतः॥७५॥ 
>   एकवारं त्रिवार वा दशवारमथापि वा। भूमावश्मनि वा सव्र्वे क्षिपेयुर्वाग्यताः खग।॥७६॥
>
> 74-76. The bathers should not agitate water. Then
>   coming out of the water to the bank, tying their Sikha (knot
>   of hair in the center of the head) they should take in their
>   right hand kusas and water with the gingelly seeds (sesame) and offer
>   the same in the southern direction, pouring it from the paitrka-tirtha
>   over the earth silently once, thrice or ten times.

And from [Chapter 5](https://archive.org/stream/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201#page/n761/mode/1up), The Annual Rite:

> एवं जलस्याञ्जलयो विभाज्याः पक्षयोर्द्वयोः॥ 
>   सव्र्वेषु पितृकाय्येषु पुत्रो मुख्योऽधिकारवान्॥ २६॥
>
> 26. O bird, thus the water-offering is divided. **For
>   performing the rites of the manes, the son is the proper person**.
>
> पिण्डप्रसेकस्तूष्णीञ्च पुष्पधूपादिकं तथा॥ 
>   दशमेऽहनि सम्प्राप्ते स्नानं ग्रामाद्वहिश्चरेत्॥२७॥
>
> 27. Pinda-praseka shall be done in silence and with
>   flowers, incense, etc. On the tenth day, bath should be taken
>   outside the village.
>
> तत्र त्याज्यानि वासांसि केशमश्रुनखानि च॥ 
>   विप्रः शुध्यत्पः स्पृष्ट्वा क्षत्त्रियो वाहनं तथा॥ २८॥ 
>   वैश्यः प्रतोदं रश्मीन्वा शूद्रो यष्टिं कृत क्रियः॥ 
>   मृतादल्पवयोभिश्च सपिण्डैः परिवापनम्॥ २९॥
>
> 28-29. **Then they should leave their old clothes, hair,
>   beard and nails.** Brahmana is purified by touching water,
>   Ksatriya by touching vehicle, Vaisya by touching a goad (or a
>   whip) or reins, and Sudra by touching stick after performing
>   the rites. **The relatives, younger in age, should undergo shave.**

In doing all of the above, the objective is to purify oneself after a death in the family which is considered a period of aśauca (अशौच).

As [mentioned](https://archive.org/stream/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201#page/n760/mode/1up) earlier in the same chapter:

> अपनोद्यन्त्विदं कालादिभिराशु निषेधकृत्॥ निण्डाध्ययनदानादेः पुंगतोऽतिशयो हि तत् ॥९॥ 
>   दशाह शावमाशौच सपिण्डेषु विधीयते॥ जननेऽप्येवमेव स्यान्निपुणां शुद्धिमिच्छताम् ॥१०॥
>
> 9-10. The ten-day-period of aśauca is prescribed for the relatives of the deceased on the father's side. This commences from the hour of birth, also with a view to obtain purity.

Also, from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16133/2995) answer, the [Dharma Sindhu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) is supposed to contain the following verse which suggests that, for everyone, their pāpa is attached to the hair; so by getting rid of your head hair, symbolically, you are getting rid of your pāpa or sins and then qualify for visiting a sacred pilgrimage site. The same reasoning can be applied to removal of one's hair during funeral rites.

> tIrthopavAsa kartavya sirasomundanAnicha sirogatAni pApAni yAntimandanatho yatah