# Is it okay to dispose a dog's dead body in the river?

Tags: rituals, moksha, death, animals, cremation

My dog passed away last night and as far as the rituals in my family are concerned, we have to dispose the dead body into the river. But most of my relatives and friends are now saying we should have buried it in the ground. I am stressed and feeling guilty about it now. Any idea whether the disposal in the river is acceptable? Will my dog get moksha or a better next life from this?

Comment: [Related but not duplicate] [Do Hindus mourn the death of animals the same way they mourn their deceased relatives?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16931/3500)

Comment: Just an opinion, it should be burried because it will be helpful for Earth in lot ways. But if you will put it in river then it will make water of river dirty and non-drinkable for animals which is not in favour of nature. Just give his body to Mother Earth.

Comment: Why not cremate it, burn the body, collect the ashes and charred bones from the pyre and dispose them into the river.

Comment: Animals, children and sages are usually buried as they are already in a way liberated and their emotions and ego are controlled by Prakriti but not by themselves and hence law of Karma is not valid on them and their spirits/minds usually not roam for not finding peace as they are not attached to material world unlike normal people who need proper cremation and rituals after death.

Comment: Personally, I would bury it in the ground, irrespective of the Hindu rituals. This leaves the river potable and stops the spread of diseases by exposing the dead animal in the water