# Antyesti for dogs

Tags: animals, antyeshti

Jai Sri Ramakrsna!

Why do we Hindus not perform cremation for dogs (& other animals)? If we are to move past this body into the next, are not all creatures subject to this?

If anyone does know how to perform antyesti for dogs, please advise.

Jai Sri Mā

Comment: If it was needed then scriptures would have certainly prescribed the same but to my limited knowledge I don't think there is any such instructions found in scriptures but i may be wrong.

Comment: But the following answer shows that Asuchi equally applies on the household if a pet dies -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16951/4732

Comment: As far as I know for us Hindus there is no practice of cremating dogs, and I believe that your point makes sense of cremating all creatures such as dogs. I would assume that the process in similar of creating a dead human, eventually we burn them and take their ashes and immerse it into a river.

Comment: We do what scripture says to do as we assert the vedas. If the vedas do not assert, then there is no need. There is no 'why'