# Is shaving or hair cutting not allowed for both the father and his children on the same day?

Tags: practice

Is shaving or hair cutting not allowed for both father and his children on the same day? Any reason?

[Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16537/why-shave-hair-after-parents-die?s=5%7C29.9885)

Comment: In Hindu practice on the death of an ancestor - paternal - the males in the family shave off their hair completely.  Therefore the belief, that father and his children should not cut their hair on the same day - especially if the grand father / grand uncles are still alive - as it may be an ill omen of pending death of one of them.

Comment: Can you tell me where you came across such thing?

Comment: our villagers follow this system, we too @TheDestroyer